# What does “忘れてしまう生き物” mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, relative-clauses

> この間、時間を見つけては、過去の歴史をひもといてみたのだが、再認識させられたのは、人間というのは、どれほど多くの涙とともに飲み下した教訓であっても、喉元を過ぎたとたんに**忘れてしまう生き物**であるということだった.

Especially, what is "忘れてしまう生き物" supposed to mean in "喉元を過ぎたとたんに忘れてしまう生き物であるということだった" ?

Comment: Can you understand the meaning of this: 「人間というのは、教訓を得たとたんに、その教訓を忘れてしまう生き物である」?

Comment: @Gradius:"その教訓を忘れてしまう生き物である" = "In that lesson there are the forgotten ones"; is that the right translation ?

Comment: I'm sorry but i still can't grasp the meaning, maybe a rough translation might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from your reply to Gradius’s comment on the question, I am afraid that you have trouble understanding relative clauses.

- 人間は生き物である。  Human is a creature.
- 人間は**教訓を忘れる**生き物である。  Human is a creature **which forgets lessons**.

In addition, …てしまう adds the meaning of “regrettably” or “unfortunately.”

- 人間は**教訓を忘れてしまう**生き物である。   Human is a creature **which, regrettably, forgets lessons**.

I will not try a translation of the whole sentence, but I hope that this gives you a small nudge in the right direction.